# Can I view/modify the Redux store using Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, google-chrome-devtools, react-redux

React Dev Tools is great for working with Redux, I can simply go in and modify props / state to see the affect on the relevant Container.

However if the required Container isn't mounted I need to directly modify the Redux store to make it appear. Is this possible with Chrome Dev Tools, I am able to find the Redux store, it is the top level `<Provider />` component, I can even see the `getState` method, but is there anyway to modify the underlying state?

[image: React dev tools Provider]

Comment: This video explains how to connect redux devtool to basic react redux app - https://youtu.be/TSOVLXQPWgA

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment under the accepted post but it's currently redirecting to a porn site.
This is the correct link: https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, you can. There is a great [Redux DevTools Extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/) for Chrome/Firefox/Electron which adds a new Redux tab to devtools:

[image]

You can import and export current store, go back in history, change whatever you want and much more.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I've switched from redux-devtools, and also realised that one doesn't simply 'modify props' in redux as it shouldn't be mutated. The ability to dispatch actions into the store is great though.

Comment: Note that currently you can't actually edit the state by hand – you have to go through a reducer. The maintainer intends to implement this in version 3 of the Redux DevTools: https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/502

Comment: Ability to edit state by hand still does not exist, years after originally being requested